# Ansible find only files which have changed

Tags: ansible-2.x

I'm trying to look for a pattern in Postgres configuration files, and
only wants to find changed files that match the search pattern.

```
---
- name: Query postgres pattern matched files
  hosts: pghosts
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:



    - name: "Find postgres conf files"
      find:
       paths: "/srv/postgresql/config/conf.d"
       patterns: "*.conf"
       file_type: "file"
      register: search_files

    - name: "grep postgres conf files with searchpattern"
      shell: "grep -i 'pg_show_plans' {{ item.path | basename }}"
      args:
        chdir: "/srv/postgresql/config/conf.d"
      loop: "{{ search_files.files }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.path | basename }}"
      ignore_errors: true

    - name: "find changed files"
      debug:
       msg: "{{ search_files.files |map(attribute='path') }}"
```

These are the changed files:

```
changed: [pgsql14.techlab.local] => (item=00_global_default.conf)
...ignoring
changed: [pgsql13.techlab.local] => (item=00_global_default.conf)
...ignoring
```

How do I get only those filenames, which realy have changed, and passed the pattern test.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I do now have simplified the code which works for me:

```
 - name: read the postgres conf file
      shell: cat /srv/postgresql/config/conf.d/00_global_default.conf
      register: user_accts1

    - name: a task that only happens if the string exists
      when: user_accts1.stdout.find('pg_show_plans') != -1
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        content: "{{ user_accts1.stdout }}"
        dest: 'fileresults/{{ inventory_hostname }}.00_global_default.out'
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: read the postgres conf file
      shell: cat /srv/postgresql/config/conf.d/01_sizing_specific.conf
      register: user_accts2

    - name: a task that only happens if the string exists
      when: user_accts2.stdout.find('pg_show_plans') != -1
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        content: "{{ user_accts2.stdout }}"
        dest: 'fileresults/{{ inventory_hostname }}.01_sizing_specific.out'
      delegate_to: localhost


    - name: read the postgres conf file
      shell: cat /srv/postgresql/config/conf.d/02_local_overrides.conf
      register: user_accts3

    - name: a task that only happens if the string exists
      when: user_accts3.stdout.find('pg_show_plans') != -1
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        content: "{{ user_accts3.stdout }}"
        dest: 'fileresults/{{ inventory_hostname }}.02_local_overrides.out'
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).